# should I run nginx for static content on port 81 or set it up as reverse proxy to apache?

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, reverse-proxy

should I run nginx for static content on port 81 or set it up as reverse proxy to apache?

Which is a better idea and why? I'm currently simply running nginx on port 81. i was wondering if there are any benefits as running it on port 80 instead and proxy to apache that sits on 8080 for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have clients in the corporate world than having a site that servers content on non-standard ports may cause issues. A lot of companies will only allow certain ports (80,443, sometimes 8080) out. This obviously isn't a universal standard but having someone email you saying your page loads but has no images or css can be a bit frustrating.

Answer (score 1):

I find it a hassle to use a non standard port to handle HTTP. The devs have to make sure to always add the port option and secondly tomorrow if you decide to use a CDN you wouldn't be able to.

The other option could be that you configure another subdomain like static.yourdomain.com and don't proxy it.

Comment: What Pratik Amin said is also true.